# Dense subfilter of selective ultrafilter

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, ultrafilters, filters

Given selective ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\omega$ and dense filter $\mathcal{F_1}=\{A\subset\omega~|~\rho(A)=1\}$, where $\rho(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap n|}{n}$ if the limit exists. Let $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{F_1}\cap\mathcal{U}$.

**Question:** Does there exist a family $\{A_i\subset\omega\}_{i<\omega},~A_i=\{a_{ik}\}_{k<\omega}$ of pairwise disjoint subsets such that for any $B\in\mathcal{F}$ we have:
$$
\{a_{ik}~|~i,k\in B\}\in\mathcal{U}
$$

**Remark:** The question is equivalent formulation of [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325925/the-property-of-the-dense-subfilter-of-a-selective-ultrafilter) which still has no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is negative. The equivalent question was answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325925/the-property-of-the-dense-subfilter-of-a-selective-ultrafilter) by Andreas Blass